Commencement and repeal dates in UK Acts of Parliament - meaning of "From and after"
I am researching the Turnpike Roads Act 1766 (7 Geo. 3. c. 40), a Consolidation Act passed in 1767. Full text on archive.org here:
Section 40 of the act provides that "this act, and the several powers, provisions, regulations, clauses and matters therein contained, shall commence and take effect on the twenty ninth day of September next ensuing":
This act received royal assent on 29 June 1767, meaning that the act's commencement was 29 September 1767.
However, section 61 of the act provides for the repeal of several acts "from and after the twenty eight day of September next" 
Does "from and after" in this context mean the day after 28 September 1767, i.e., 29 September 1767 (the commencement of the act)?
Or, is there a situation where there is one day where the laws the consolidation act replaces are repealed, but the act replacing them is not in force?

I suppose the interpretation could be that the repeal takes place at the end of 28 September (as if it were 11:59:59.99999... PM) and the new provisions take effect at the beginning of 29 September, so that no time actually elapses in between.

I think that "from and after" does not include the stated date. Similar language in other Acts:

The several Acts and Parts of Acts in the Schedule hereto annexed shall continue in force until and throughout the last Day of October in the present Year, and shall from and after that Day be repealed to the Extent following ...
(Criminal Statutes Repeal Act 1861, s.1)


[Various Acts] shall be and continue in force until and throughout the Thirty-first Day of October in the present Year, and shall from and after that Day, as to that Part of the United Kingdom called England, be repealed ...
(Game Act 1831, s.1)

These both show a clearly non-inclusive sense of "from and after".
There are other statutes where the sense is not so clear, like the Acts of Union 1707 which refer to various things being the case "from and after" the Union. That would seem to include day one (the first of May, defined in Article 1), though the grammar is a bit different here in any case.
Legislative drafting in earlier times was not as precise as it is now, so it's not a given that these words are always meant to exclude the start date. But in the context of the question I'd be astonished if there was an intent of creating a single day of anarchy between the two regimes.

"a single day of anarchy between the two regimes" but if you need a pretext for The Purge meets Poldark...

In February 1791, Congress passed five statutes concerning the state of Vermont. The first one stated that that state would be admitted to the Union on the 4th day of March, exactly two weeks after the bill was introduced in both houses of Congress and passed by both houses and signed by the president, all on the same day. I don't remember the details of the others. I think one of them said how many representatives Vermont would have in Congress, and another created a federal judgeship, and another provided for the construction of a customs house or something like that on an island in Lake Champlain. (I think ships transporting goods from Quebec to Vermont were to be inspected there or something?) However, I recall one of them saying it was to be in effect "from and after the 3rd day of March." Everything about the context makes it crystal-clear that it was to be in effect on the 4th of March and not on the 3rd. Congress went out of its way to avoid taking any position on the disputed question of whether Vermont was or was not within the boundaries of the U.S.A. before its admission to the Union. (The polity that was officially called "the State of Vermont" before that was neither one of the states of the Union nor a territory governed under an organizing act passed by Congress. Its constitution had been drafted by statesmen in Vermont and its government had been functioning under that constitution for more than a decade. I think Vermont was probably the only state admitted by Congress that did not acquire a new constitution or a new governor or other new officers when it was admitted: the constitution and governor and other officers simply went on as before. That unique situation is reflected in the statute admitting Vermont to the Union, where it is stated that the entity that had submitted the petition for admission was "the State of Vermont.")

The state of Vermont isn't even in the UK, so what's your point?

@TobySpeight : My point is that this locution has had some currency.

@TobySpeight : And also, notice that the article of legislation to which I referred was not in Vermont and was in no sense an act of the legislature of Vermont. It was the Congress of the United States. And as I said, it shows that the locution had some currency among English-speaking legislators.
